# Enumerate directories in Parallel consumes very high physical memory usage

Tags: c#, io, task-parallel-library, ienumerable

I wrote an utility which will search all the fixed drives in a system for files of certain extension. Some of the drives contains millions of folders (say, 30 million for example) and the files can be found at a different depth(say, 6th/7th sub folder). Find below the function I am using,

```
private void ReadDirectories(string targetDirectory)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory).AsParallel();
        ConcurrentBag<string> filesBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>(files);
        Parallel.ForEach(filesBag, (file) =>
       {
           Interlocked.Increment(ref totalFileCount);
           if (extension is a text/excel/word file )
           {
               try
               {
                   // Some logic here
               }
               catch (AggregateException Aex)
               {
                   Log("Aggregate exception thrown. " + Aex.Message + Aex.StackTrace + Aex.InnerException);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Log("File read failed: " + file + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
                   return; // This is break equivalent in Parallel.ForEach

               }
           }

       });

        IEnumerable<string> directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(targetDirectory).AsParallel();
        ConcurrentBag<string> directoryBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>(directories);
        Parallel.ForEach(directoryBag, (subDirectory) =>
         {
             try
             {
                 ReadDirectories(subDirectory);
             }
             catch (AggregateException Aex)
             {
                 Log("Aggregate exception thrown. " + Aex.Message + Aex.StackTrace + Aex.InnerException);
             }
             catch (UnauthorizedAccessException Uaex)
             {
                 Log("Unauthorized exception: " + Uaex.Message + Uaex.StackTrace + Uaex.InnerException);
                 return;
             }
             catch (AccessViolationException Aex)
             {
                 Log("Access violation exception: " + Aex.Message + Aex.StackTrace + Aex.InnerException);
                 return;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Log("Error while reading directories and files : " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
                 return;
             }
         });

    }
```

The issue I am facing is, once the application starts enumerating folders the physical memory gets consumed more and more and it reaches its peak (99%) after sometime. At this point no other activities can be performed. But my application memory is about 80 -90 MB through out its run. Want to know the reason why the physical memory usage is so high, Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: So, does the same behavior occur without the `// Some logic here`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, the same effect even if i simply enumerate the directories without performing any action.

Comment: This is bound to bottle neck, there to 2 `Parallel.ForEach` and a `AsParallel`, this is a parallel recursive method who knows how many threadpool threads are going to be running and how much context switching will be going on. if you want to do stuff like this in parallel i think you need a simpler approach. i suggest using one parallel method  or a queue, or actionblocks or something.

Comment: As to the memory usage, this is what .net and operating systems do, you are probably creating a lot of managed and unmanaged garbage, the operating system just wont aggressively give back\take back memory. Since this is only a simple method id suggest using a benchmarker and profiler and try a couple of more designs and see which works best for you and your resources

Answer (score 2):

Consider your numbers: 30 million folders, each with probably a few files leaves you with something like 100 million strings for file and directory names. And due to the method being recursive, the bags are all kept until the end of the recursion.

So with an average file/directory name length of 100 chars, you're up to 10GB of RAM for the names only.

Comment: Rohr: I will remove the step where I am using the ConcurrentBag to store string and enumerate directly and check the results.

Answer (score 2):

As others explained, storing so many strings will eat up a *lot* of memory and can't scale. Trying to enumerate folders and files in *parallel* won't speed up processing either.

It's faster to use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) or even better, [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to enumerate *all* files in the current folder and subfolders and process the *files* in parallel.

A quick and dirty option would be to use a LINQ query to filter all target files and a Parallel.ForEach to process the files, eg:

```
var extensions=new[]{".docx", ".xlsx",...};
var folder=new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
var files=from file in folder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
          where extensions.Contains(file.Extension,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
          select file;

Parallel.ForEach(files,file=>ProcessFile(file));
```

This will use roughly as many task as cores in the machine to process files. You can use more tasks by specifying a different MaxDegreeOfParallelism option:

```
var options=new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
Parallel.ForEach(files,options,ProcessFile);
```

`Parallel.ForEach` will pull file names from the `files` query as needed. It will start processing as soon as `EnumerateFiles` returns the first results instead of waiting for all file names to be loaded and cached in memory.

Comment: I tried the same, but when using EnumerateFiles I am getting unauthorized exception and the enumeration failed to proceed. I am sorting it now.

Comment: @karthik you'd get that if you tried to read a folder to which you don't have permission.